# Does windows rescale to monitors of differing resolutions?

Tags: windows, display, resolution

Here is the current resolution of my monitor :

[image]

If I purchased a higher res monitor then will windows / graphics card auto re-scale everything to this new resolution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Windows supports scaling to higher resolutions, but if and only if your moniter, graphics card AND your graphics driver supports the resolution. In some case windows may not detect the resolutions your monitor supports and may provide support for higher resolutions (which will not display correctly) or limit a you to a low resolution (more probable).

However I noticed you are using Citrix and hence the resolution may be restricted in software by administrators. If you are the admin then you need to configure the display properly.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes.

Longer answer, because it's displaying everything through Citrix, the admins may have restricted the graphics options. The full resolution of your monitor may (and probably would be) supported and used, but because of Citrix, it may not look as great as you're expecting.